# What are closed sets in $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

We have $[0,1]$ with usual topology. Open sets are of the form $[0,a)$ and $(b,1]$. Their complements are $[a,1]$ and $[0, b]$. Are these closed in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are closed sets in $[0,1]$. But there are lots of other open sets in $[0,1]$ besides those that you mentioned. For instance $(0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is also an open set in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Will (0,a] be open or closed? How should I check?

Comment: @Tam It depends. What is $a$?

Comment: An element of (0,1)

Comment: @Tam It's neither open nor closed. It is not open because you cannot express $(0,a]$ as the intersection of an open susbset of $\mathbb R$ with $[0,1]$. And it is not closed because its complement (in $[0,1]$) is $\{0\}\cup(a,1]$ which, again, you cannot express as the intersection of an open susbset of $\mathbb R$ with $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to know here:

1. The complement of an open set is always a closed set.  (Sometimes by definition, but if not then by an easy theorem.)
2. If $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ (as $[0,1]$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$), and $C$ is a closed subset of $Y$, then $C\cap Y$ is a closed subset of $Y$.

Does any of that help?